# XElement & UTF-8 Issue

Tags: unicode, utf-8, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a .NET Web Service(.asmx, not .svc) that accepts a string via HTTP POST. The strings it accepts are xml infosets I then parse via XElement.Parse. Once parsed into an XElement instance, I add a node to one of the elements within the instance.

The problem I'm having is that if a string representing an xml infoset comes through with  then for some reason, me adding a node to the element XElement throws an exception such as "' ', hexadecimal value 0x06, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 40.". I get a wide array of 0x(*) errors thrown. If I don't attempt to add nodes to the XElement, everythings fine. Here's how I'm adding the element:

```
var prospect = doc.Element("prospect");
var provider = prospect.Element("provider");

provider.Add(new XElement("id",
    new XAttribute("reservation-code",
    reservationCode)
));
```

Is there some sort of string conversion I ought to be doing somewhere?

Comment: What is the type and value of `reservationCode`?

Comment: reservationCode is a string based guid. reservationCode is actually another parameter coming in as the second parameter of the web service operation. I want to inject it into the xml passed.

Answer (score 4):

XML does not allow some Unicode characters. See [the XML 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets). Unfortunately, there is no standard way to escape those characters in XML, too. For example, you cannot escape it in valid XML using `&#x9;` because of the **Well-formedness constraint: Legal Character** (see [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-references)).

The `XElement.ToString()` has the check for those characters turned on. However, .NET does provide a way to turn character checking off. It is off by default in the `System.Xml.XmlWriter` instances. Therefore the following code will work:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the XML string of the <paramref name="xElement"/> WITHOUT CHARACTER CHECKING.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xElement"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToStringWithoutCharacterChecking(this XElement xElement)
    {
        using (System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            using (System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                xElement.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
            }
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Notice however that if you create an `System.Xml.XmlWriter` instance using `System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings`, the default is `true` for character checking. Therefore if you use `System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings` and want to turn off character checking, use:

```
XmlWriterSettings s = new XmlWriterSettings();
s.CheckCharacters = false;
using(XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(..., s))
{
    //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, which solved my problem when I using linq to xsd.
here is my code:
//not using `container.Save(new StreamWriter(toStream, new UTF8Encoding(false)));` 
instead using codes:

```
using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(new StreamWriter(toStream, new UTF8Encoding(false)), new XmlWriterSettings
            {//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709831/xelement-utf-8-issue
                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057171/xdocument-prevent-invalid-charachters
                Indent = true,
                CheckCharacters = false
            }))
            {
                XTypedServices.Save(w, container.Untyped);
            }

            toStream.Flush();
```